# Font Installation in TeX Live 2013

Tags: fonts, installing, texlive

I have the `.afm` and `.pfb` files for the Garamond Light Condensed fonts, I follow the instructions available [here](http://www.umantec.nl/fontinst/) for installation.

When I try to use them in my document they are not found by `pdflatex`; my log file contains

```
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for T1+pgm on input line 60.
LaTeX Font Info:    No file T1pgm.fd. on input line 60.
```

and

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/pgm/m/n' undefined
```

I am using TeX Live 2013 on Ubuntu, installed with TeX tools rather than apt-get.

This worked fine in TeX Live 2012. Why doesn't it work in TeX Live 2013?

Comment: I'm surprised it worked with TL 2012. TL does not look in those directories by default. You shouldn't be editing `psfonts.map` directly at all. Also map files etc. have changed their locations a bit even from 2012 to 2013. You should be running `updmap-sys` to enable the map files. I don't know what those scripts do but you need to adapt the instructions for the current edition of TL.

Comment: Use LuaTeX or XeTeX and forget about complex font installation.

Comment: Please read https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-370003.4.7

Comment: My problem is that everything is in his place. texthash, updmap-sys (with sudo) were running. the '.map' is enable...
One question: 'Font Shape undefined' are defined in what file? and Where is that file?